# Check for referrer in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, referrer

I am using backbone.js for my web application, in particular Routing and History.

So I have an URL like http://localhost/search/John+Doe.

In my router.js, I have a route like

```
search: function () {
    /* do something */
    /* Can I check here, whether I came to this page using Backbone's navigate()
       or by pasting the url in the urlbar */
}
```

In this function, is there a backbone-built-in way to check, how I came on that page: either by Backbone.router.navigate or by pasting the url in the url bar of the browser/clicking a link that brought me there?

I tried document.referrer, but it's

```
>> document.referrer
""
```

in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the latest value:

```
$(function(){
  var lastPage = 'stackoverflow.com';
  var routesObject = {
    'help': 'helpFun',
    'search': 'searchFun'
  };
  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      initialize: function() {
          this.bind('all', function(route) {
              lastPage = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];
          });
      },
      routes: routesObject,
      searchFun: function(){
          console.log(lastPage);
      },
      helpFun: function() {
          console.log(lastPage);
      }
  });
  var router = new Router();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState:false});
});
```

If You navigate to your.domain.com/yourapp#search and then to your.domain.com/yourapp#help You will see in the console the recent entered route.